# SwiperJs Z-index issue in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, z-index, swiper.js

When I applied the slider from swiperjs, my dropdowns from navbar or hamburger went backward to the slider. I had tried very much by changing the z-index of hamburger as well as swiper, but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to answer without more context, but I had somewhat the same issue

I Set the CSS styling for the hamburger menu / header:

```
z-index: 9999;
```

If you are using tailwind:

```
z-50
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
On my global scss stylesheet I set:

```
swiper-container {
   z-index: 0;
}
```

And on my navbar I set

```
navbar {
   z-index: 1;
}
```